# Chaning attr() Value with jQuery returns same

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML :

```
 <div data-name="name='john'">
   <span class="button">click</span>
 </div>
```

And the following jQuery code :

```
 $(".button").click(function() {
    con_sc = $(this).parent().data('name');
    alert(con_sc);
    if( con_sc.indexOf( "name='john'" ) !== -1 ) {          
        var con_new_value = con_sc.replace("name='john'","name=''");
        $(this).parent().attr("data-name", con_new_value);
    }
    if( con_sc.indexOf( "name=''" ) !== -1 ) {          
        var con_new_value = con_sc.replace("name=''","name='john'");
        $(this).parent().attr("data-name", con_new_value);
    }  
 });
```

The above jQuery code changes the value of data attribute from name='john' to `name=''` upon clicking the button, however when I click the same button again it shows the old value name='john' which is already changed to `name=''`, it should display `name=''` in alert. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, in the Firebug it clearly shows it has changed the data-attribute value to `name=''`. Please advise. thanks

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4c162cqk/6/)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4c162cqk/10/)**.

Use jQuery method **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** instead when you want to edit `data-*` attributes :

```
$(this).parent().data("name", con_new_value);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  con_sc = $(this).parent().data('name');

  console.log('Current data-name is ----> '+con_sc);

  if( con_sc.indexOf( "name='john'" ) !== -1 ) {  
    var con_new_value = con_sc.replace("name='john'","name=''"); 
    $(this).parent().data("name", con_new_value);

    console.log('New data-name is ----> '+$(this).parent().data("name"));
  }

  if( con_sc.indexOf( "name=''" ) !== -1 ) {
    var con_new_value = con_sc.replace("name=''","name='john'");
    $(this).parent().data("name", con_new_value);

    console.log('New data-name is ----> '+$(this).parent().data("name"));
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-name="name='john'">
  <span class="button">click</span>
</div>
```

**Change attribute in the firebug using `.attr()` :**

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  con_sc = $(this).parent().attr('data-name');

  console.log('Current data-name is ----> '+con_sc);

  if( con_sc.indexOf( "name='john'" ) !== -1 ) {  
    var con_new_value = con_sc.replace("name='john'","name=''"); 
    $(this).parent().attr("data-name", con_new_value);

    console.log('New data-name is ----> '+$(this).parent().data("name"));
  }

  if( con_sc.indexOf( "name=''" ) !== -1 ) {
    var con_new_value = con_sc.replace("name=''","name='john'");
    $(this).parent().attr("data-name", con_new_value);

    console.log('New data-name is ----> '+$(this).parent().data("name"));
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-name="name='john'">
  <span class="button">click</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that already but it doesn't change the original value.

Comment: @Themer what version of Jquery are you using? Some of the older versions, don't actually map values set with .data to data attributes?

Comment: Thanks Zakaria, I was looking in Firebug to the data attribute, and it was not changing the value, and it still doesnt change but infact it works.. I dont know why in Firebug it doesn't change. I also needs to change HTML in data attribute. thanks.

Comment: If you want to change it in the firebug you shouldn't use `data()` when you get attribute but `attr()`, check my update.

Comment: Thanks Zakaria, I was using data while getting, thanks a lot.. much appreciated. I wasted 1 hour on this.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `.data` instead of `.attr` to update `data-` attributes

updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4c162cqk/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the data like this: `$(this).parent().data('name', '')`?